# What is the difference between && and | in bash script?

Tags: bash

Let's take the two lines below which give us two different results.

```
p=$(cd ~ && pwd) ; echo $p
p=$(cd ~ |  pwd) ; echo $p
```

How do the two differ?

Comment: @heemayl Thanks. May you extract the differences on my case? Thanks.

Comment: **Hint:** The commands on either side of `|` run in subshells.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `p=$(cd ~ && pwd)`:

- The command substitution, `$()`, runs in a subshell
- `cd ~` changes directory to `~` (your home), if `cd` succeeds (`&&`) then `pwd` prints the directory name on STDOUT, hence the string saved on `p` will be your home directory e.g. `/home/foobar`

In `p=$(cd ~ |  pwd)`:

- Again `$()` spawns a subshell
- The commands on both sides of `|` run in respective subshells (and both starts off at the same time)
- so `cd ~` is done in a subshell, and `pwd` in a **separate** subshell
- so you would get only the STDOUT from `pwd` i.e. from where you run the command, this can be any directory as you can imagine, hence `p` will contain the directory name from where the command is invoked, not your home directory

Comment: What's the purpose of the pipe between the commands? `cd ~` doesn't produce any output, and `pwd` doesn't read any input.

Comment: The second command is essentially equivalent to `(cd ~);p=$(pwd)` isn't it?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it's what OP has used, and I'm just explaining it for him.

Answer (score 9):

The core issue is how the operators `&&` and `|` connect the two commands.

The `&&` connects the commands via the exit code.
The `|` connects the two commands via the file descriptors (stdin, stdout).

Lets simplify first. We can remove the assignment and write:

```
echo $(cd ~ && pwd)
echo $(cd ~ | pwd)
```

We can even remove the command execution sub-shell to analyze this:

```
$ cd ~ && pwd
$ cd ~ | pwd
```

## &&

If we change the prompt to show the directory where the commands are executed, something like `PS1='\w\$ '`, we will see this:

```
/tmp/user$ cd ~ && pwd
/home/user
~$
```

- The command `cd ~` changed the "present directory" to the home of the actual user that is executing the command (`/home/user`).
- As the result of the command was successful (exit code 0), the next command after the && is executed
- And the "present working directory" is printed.
- The running shell has changed its `pwd` to `~` as is shown by the prompt of `~$`.

If the change of directory were unsuccessful (exit code not 0) for some reason (directory doesn't exist, permissions block reading the directory) the next command will not be executed.

Example:

```
/tmp/user$ false && pwd
/tmp/user$ _
```

The exit code of 1 from `false` prevents the execution of the next command.

Thus, the exit code of "command 1" is what affects the "command 2".

Now, the effects of the whole command:

```
/tmp/user$ echo $(cd ~ && pwd)
/home/user
/tmp/user$ _
```

The directory was changed, but inside a sub-shell `$(…)`, the changed directory is printed `/home/user`, but is immediately discarded as the sub-shell closes. The pwd returns to be the initial directory (`/tmp/user`).

## |

This is what happens:

```
/tmp/user$ cd ~ | pwd
/tmp/user
/tmp/user$ _
```

The meta-character `|` (not a true operator) signals the shell to create what is called a "Pipe", (in bash) each command on each side of the pipe (`|`) are set inside each own sub-shell, first the right side command, then, the left one. The input file descriptor (`/dev/stdin`) of the right command is connected to the output descriptor (`/dev/stdout`) and then both commands are started and left to interact. The left command (`cd -`) has no output, and, also, the right command (`pwd`) accepts no input. So, each one runs independently inside each own sub-shell.

- The `cd ~` changes the pwd of one shell.
- The `pwd` prints the (completely independent) pwd of the other sub-shell.

The changes on each shell are discarded when the pipe ends, the external sub-shell has not changed the pwd.

That's why the two commands are connected only by "file descriptors".
In this case, there is nothing sent, and nothing read.

The whole command:

```
$ echo "$(cd ~ | pwd)"
```

Will just print the directory where the command was executed.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if you meant '|' or '||' in your second case.

'|' in a shell pipes the output of one command to the input of another - a common use case is something like:
`curl http://abcd.com/efgh | grep ijkl`
i.e. run a command, and use another command to process the output of a command.

In the example you give, it is fairly non-nonsensical, as 'cd' typically does not generate any output, and 'pwd' does not expect any input.

'&&' and '||' are partner commands though. They are designed to be used the same way as logical "and" and "or" operators in most languages. However, the optimisations that are performed give them a specific behaviour that is a shell programming paradigm.

To determine the result of a logical "and" operation, you only need to evaluate the second condition if the first condition succeeds - if the first condition fails, the overall result will always be false.

To determine the result of a logical "or" operation, you only need to evaluate the second condition if the first condition fails - if the first condition succeeds, the overall result will always be true.

So, in the shell, if you have `command1 && command2` `command2` will only be executed when `command1` has completed and returned a successful result code.
If you have `command1 || command2` `command2` will be executed when `command1` completes if `command1` returns a failure code.

Another common paradigm is to have `command1` be a test command - this generates a single line if/then statement - for example:

`[ "$VAR" = "" ] && VAR="Value if empty"`

Is a (long winded) way of assigning a value to a variable if it is currently empty.

There are many examples of the use of this process elsewhere on Stack Exchange